# Dojo Digit Theme rendering form_for submit input without text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, dojo, dijit.form

I have the following Rails form_for definition. As you can see in the screen shot, it is not rendering the "Sign In" text for the Submit input. I have also included the resulting HTML.

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :dojoType => "dijit.form.Form") do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.label :login %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :login, {:dojoType => "dijit.form.TextBox"} %></p>

  <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password, {:dojoType => "dijit.form.TextBox"} %></p>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <p><%= f.check_box :remember_me, {:dojoType => "dijit.form.CheckBox"} %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></p>
  <% end -%>

  <p><%= f.submit "Sign in", {:dojoType => "dijit.form.Button"} %></p>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

[image]

HTML

```
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton" dir="ltr" widgetid="user_submit"><span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" dojoattachevent="ondijitclick:_onButtonClick">
    <span class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" dojoattachpoint="titleNode,focusNode" wairole="button" waistate="labelledby-user_submit_label" role="button" aria-labelledby="user_submit_label" id="user_submit" tabindex="0" style="-webkit-user-select: none; ">
        <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon" dojoattachpoint="iconNode"></span><span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">●</span>
            <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" id="user_submit_label" dojoattachpoint="containerNode"></span>
        </span>
    </span>
    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign In" class="dijitOffScreen" dojoattachpoint="valueNode">
</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ERB code is correct, it is working fine. 
It seems you have trouble on main layout. 
You must add your dojo script definition   section. 
I recommend you to create a clean new layout for this concept.
My head is on dojo.html.erb

<%= stylesheet_link_tag "default" %>
   
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.5/dojo/dojo.xd.js' , :djconfig => "parseOnLoad: true"%>

Comment: Thanks to the pointer to the csrf_meta_tag. But this did not seem to address the issue. Are you using a dijit theme? If so, where/how do you include the stylesheet_link_tag?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is simple, if you check samples on dojo, button is button type, but rails produces input type, so it is not working.
You can write on erb file,

```
<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" type="button">Click me too!</button>
```

it is working, 
or you can write your helper script on application_helper.rb